# По какой-то причине код отказыватется работать слеш команды

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

проблема в том, что я пытаюсь совместить коды через префикс и через '/', но выдает ошибку

```
TypeError: Client.__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Код:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import app_commands 
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='=', intents=intents)



class aclient(discord.Client):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(intents)
        self.synced = False 

    async def on_ready(self):
        await self.wait_until_ready()
        if not self.synced: 
            await tree.sync(guild = discord.Object(id='id сервака'))
            self.synced = True
        print(f"We have logged in as {self.user}.")

client = aclient() 
tree = app_commands.CommandTree(client)

@tree.command(guild = discord.Object(id='id сервака'), name = 'help', description='ur help') 
async def slash2(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message(" я устал..", ephemeral = False)
bot.run('')
```

Полностью ошибка:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "F:\test.py", line 27, in <module>
        client = aclient() 
      File "F:\test.py", line 17, in __init__
        super().__init__(intents)
    TypeError: Client.__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: Ошибку нужно приводить полностью в вопросе, чтобы понятно было, к какой строке кода она относится и т.д. Не экономьте место, покажите ошибку целиком.

Comment: изменил, по какой-то причине сайт считал это кодом и не разрешал полностью. кинул в конец кода

Comment: Странно, конструктор `discord.Client` почему-то не хочет принимать параметры, в данном случае `intents`. Попробуйте `super().__init__(intents=intents)`

Comment: после изменений программа запускается, но команды которые через '/' игнорирует + не пишет в консоль текст

Comment: Так у вас написано `command_prefix='='`, значит перед командой должно быть видимо `=`, а не `/`?

Comment: '/' подрузамивает команду, которая как будто встроена в дискорд, мне как раз нужно, чтобы выводило.
если вы пользовались дискорд ботами, думаю понимаете о чем я.
к тому же он должен в консоль выводить "we have logged in as (наименование бота)", что он не делает

Comment: я как раз и пытаюсь сделать чтобы работала и '/' команда и через префикс, то есть через '=', но не пойму почему не работает.

Comment: при попытке запустить команду пишет такую ошибку:  raise CommandNotFound(name, parents)
discord.app_commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Application command 'help' not found

Comment: заметил особенность, если в конце поменять вместо bot.run() на client.run() будут работать команды через '/' иначе же только '='.